# ASP.NET: validation for dynamically added textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have custom control inherited from `TableCell` with dynamically created controls:

```
public class CustomCell : TableCell
{
    private TextBox _tbx;
    private CompareValidator _val;
    ...

    public CustomCell(...)
    {
        _tbx = new TextBox{...};
        base.Controls.Add(_tbx);

        _val = new CompareValidator();
        _val.ControlToValidate = _tbx.ID;
        _val.ErrorMessage = "error message";
        base.Controls(_val);
    }
```

}

So, there is table with these cells on page. But when there is invalid value in one cell, every other cell show error message.  How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide different ID on all textbox.

Comment: Try to use Behavior ID

Comment: @Jayesh Goyani, of course, IDs are different

Comment: You should dynamically add controls in the control's `OnInitialize` event.

Comment: you can pass different id for the different table row and textfield. But why aren't using Jquery?